# Rewriting URL not working when using three segments

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-config

This code works perfectly to url rewrite 2 segments of the URL.

For example

```
/nottinghamshire/newark
```

However, if I add `string t = Request.QueryString["t"].Replace("-", " ").ToLower().Replace(".aspx", "")` to the mix, meaning

```
/nottinghamshire/newark/plumbers
```

It fails, and 404s like so:
[image]

yet this works?

```
?r=nottinghamshire&c=newark&t=plumbers
```

This is my code

Web config:

```
  <rule name="rewritereview">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.js|\.css|\.img|\.scimg" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/city.aspx?r={R:1}&amp;c={R:2}&amp;t={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
```

Code behind on city.aspx.cs

```
string r = Request.QueryString["r"].Replace("-", " ").ToLower();
string c = Request.QueryString["c"].Replace("-", " ").ToLower().Replace(".aspx","");
string t = Request.QueryString["t"].Replace("-", " ").ToLower().Replace(".aspx", "");

if (r != null && c != null && t != null)
{
  // populate page
}
else // 404?
{

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you try the "?r=nottinghamshire&c=newark&t=plumbers" what do you get for the values of r, c, & t

Comment: @MRxParkour, I get exactly what I ask for - nottingham, newark, plumbers as the values, which is why I'm guessing it's web config related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Updating the match URL. adding an extra "/([^/]+)"

```
<match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$" />
```

Comment: You, sir, are a legend. How did I miss that?

Comment: Well regex does tend to be a jumbled mess, imo.  For future reference, https://regex101.com/ comes in quite handy for debugging that kind of stuff